# Fixing HTML form in CSS what i have to do more

Tags: html, css

my homework
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EYvx.png)

and this what i do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0mZ9.png)
 what i have to do more

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    #box1{
      box-sizing: content-box; width:300px; height:200px; padding:150px; border: 1px solid;
    

     </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div  id="box1"   margin>
     <form action="must.txt">
        Frist Name :<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Last Name : <input type="text" name="lname" ><br>
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" ><br>
        Email : <input type="email" name="email" ><Br>
        Birthday : <input type="date" name="Birthday" > <br>
        Gender : <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male">Male
                 <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female">Female
                </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Can you specify what problems you are having, what you tried to solve them, etc.?

Comment: Do you want add "Register Form" label?

Comment: Realistically, you should be telling *us* what else has to be done. Is there something missing that you're having trouble with, specifically? What attempts and/or research have you made towards meeting that requirement? We can't answer for your teacher/professor to tell you whether you've done enough or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made some arrangements. You can do the rest by searching. Good luck with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    #box1{ 
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div  id="box1">
<fieldset style="padding:50px">
<legend>Register Form</legend>
     <form action="must.txt">
        First Name :<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Last Name : <input type="text" name="lname" ><br>
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" ><br>
        Email : <input type="email" name="email" ><Br>
        Birthday : <input type="date" name="Birthday" > <br>
        Gender : <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male">Male
                 <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female">Female<br>
                <center><button type="submit" style="margin:5px">Submit</button><button onclick="ResetFields()">Reset</button></center> 
      </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add confirm password and confirm email:

Confirm Password : `<input type="password" name="confirm_password" >`

Confirm Email : `<input type="email" name="confirm_email" >`